# Xampp htdocs folder doesn't reconize when i change files

Tags: php, xampp

I don't know if this has been already asked, i searched almost everywhere i can think of, but i didn't find a solution.

**My problem consists in:**

I start xampp panel(which is saved in E disk and not the main one), i start Apache and MySQL, than i have saved in a folder called "site"(inside htdocs)some php files with more folders like: css, javas, ect.

What is happening is that every time i modify any file that is inside a folder in the folder "site", the localhost/site, doesn't recognize the change, but once i change the folder name ("site"), into something else and access it again (localhost/anothername), the exact file/files i changed are recognized and work.

If from here i try to change another file that i didn't modify before i have to rechange the name again and so on.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like browser cache, perhaps. Try running in incognito/private mode to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Well in incognito mode actually worked fine, didn't test too much cuz i have not that much time, i will control better later, but for now it worked fine.

Comment: So, if you press and hold the shift key while clicking the reload button, does that change anything? (forces cache reload)

Comment: I encountered the same problem i mentioned, but for some reason reopening the localhost/foldername fixed it, i will make more tests and confirm if this is the solution

Comment: When i shift reloaded it started working, i have to do it for every file i change but i suppose once i did it, it will work until i close the server.

Comment: Yes, that's weird to have to do that every time, which is why I thought the incognito would have helped.